# Angular - Remove a div block from an array of blocks

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a block of html divs.

```
  <div class="my-div-1">
    <div class="my-div-2">
      <div class="my-div-3">
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Among this block there is a div with the class my-div-2. How can I remove this, but at the same time, the divs with class my-div-1 and class my-div-2 should remain. It should look like the one shown below.

```
  <div class="my-div-1">
      <div class="my-div-3">
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Important: It is necessary to do this in such a way that the reference to the object my-div-1 is not lost.

Comment: I'm unclear what the actual problem is here. Is this your template or from somewhere else? Is this a theoretical exercise? It would likely be more performant to just style around having the extra div if it's from a template you don't have access to

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="my-div-1" ngIf="myFlag">
    <div class="my-div-2">
      <div class="my-div-3">
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
<div class="my-div-1" ngIf="!myFlag">
      <div class="my-div-3">
        <p>Hello World</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Based on myFlag, you'd have my-div-2 in the html.

Comment: I tried this option. The object reference is lost. Therefore this option is not suitable. In simple words, this is a different object.

Comment: @New York is my city can you explain what do you mean by object reference is lost. Object reference for which variable is lost ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this.
In the template:

```
<div #block class="my-div-1">
  div 1
  <div class="my-div-2"> 
    div 2
    <div class="my-div-3"> 
      div 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in component:

```
    @ViewChild('block', {read: ElementRef, static: true}) block!: ElementRef; 
  private readonly renderer = inject(Renderer2);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const childrenNodes = [...this.block.nativeElement.children];
    const queredNode = this.queryForInnerNode(childrenNodes);
    if(queredNode){
      const parentOfQueredNode = this.renderer.parentNode(queredNode);
      const innerContent = queredNode.children;
      this.renderer.removeChild(parentOfQueredNode, queredNode);
      this.appendExtractedContent(parentOfQueredNode, [...innerContent]);
    }
  }
  queryForInnerNode(childNodes: any): any {
    let queredNode: any = undefined;
    childNodes.forEach((childNode: any) => {
      queredNode = childNode.className === 'my-div-2' 
     ? childNode 
     : this.queryForInnerNode([...childNode.childNodes]);
    });
    return queredNode;
  }

  appendExtractedContent(parentNode: any, nodes: any[]) : void {
    nodes.forEach((node) => {
      this.renderer.appendChild(parentNode, node);
    })
  }
```

You get the most outer element with

```
 @ViewChild('block', {read: ElementRef, static: true}) block!: ElementRef;
```

Next you get children nodes with:

```
const childrenNodes = [...this.block.nativeElement.children];
```

and you search through the nodes tree with:

```
 queryForInnerNode(childNodes: any): any | undefined
```

If element was found you get the contet of the node and manipulate the DOM with `renderer` service.